# Install OpenCV for Java on Heroku server

Tags: java, opencv, heroku, installation

When I execute this code on Heroku server I get this message:

[image]

How to install **OpenCV for Java** on **Heroku** server?

Comment: My code :                                                                                      @Override
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
  Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
     out.println("mat = " + mat.dump());

Comment: Show us your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Here is a capture of my pom.xml http://hpics.li/8141664

Comment: In my local server tomcat it works but on the server heroku it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You are using `nu.pattern:opencv` which is unmaintained. The [README](https://github.com/PatternConsulting/opencv/blob/stable/README.md) says "Due to time constraints, this package is not actively maintained. As of December 29, 2015, it's strongly recommended users migrate to [OpenPnP's excellent fork of this project](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv), generously and regularly maintained by Jason von Nieda."

Try using this Maven dependency instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0-1</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also need to [load the native library](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv#api) as described in the documentation.